# Using javascript to Capitalize, Break it up with a new line every, and Add String to the beginning of each new line

Tags: javascript, string, character, line, capitalize

Using javascript to (1) Capitalize all characters from a user input string, (2) break it up with a new line every 45 characters, and (3) add a certain string  ("///////" for example) to the beginning of each new line.

I want a simple application where I can copy and paste a string of text, and have a function do the above.

For example:
Copy and paste "*I am new to JavaScript, so even this simple code is very difficult to write*" and get the following:

> "
>   //////I AM NEW TO JAVASCRIPT, SO EVEN THIS SIMPLE C
>   //////ODE IS VERY DIFFICULT TO WRITE
>   "

I would like to, in the future, make it so that it doesn't cut off a word like that in the middle, and can use the SPACES to find where the new line should be, but that seems like a little much right now.

All I have is the Capitalization function working:

```js
var txt = prompt("Enter string of text");
var cap = txt.toUpperCase();
alert(cap);
```

but I want it to run all three functions at once and `alert()` the final product.

Comment: What do you mean "*run all three functions at once*"?

Answer (score 1):

In a "functional programming style", you can do it like this:

```js
var txt = prompt("Enter string of text");
var cap = txt.toUpperCase().split('').reduce(function(agg, item, i) {
  if(i % 45 === 0) {
    if(i > 0) {
      agg.push('\r\n');
    }
    agg.push('//////');
  }
  agg.push(item);
  return agg;
  }, []).join('');
alert(cap);
```

Essentially what happens here is that the string is:

1. Converted to upper case. Then...
2. Split into an array of single characters. Then...
3. The array is "reduced"<sup>1</sup> to a new array with interwoven new lines and "separator" string (`//////`). Then...
4. The new array is joined to form a new string.

<sup>1</sup> Reducing an array is an operation that iterates array items sequentially, and incrementally generating a single "reduced" result. Typically this is used in scenarios such as summing multiple values. In this code this is not a "logically correct" usage of this function as it doesn't reduce anything, but it does enable a functional style solution.

Comment: Since the OP seems to be new at Javascript you may want to add an explanation of how the code works.

Comment: @XO - yeah, I guess you're right, though I always have hopes this will encourage self-learning instead of spoon feeding

Comment: Even so, a little description would help the OP and future readers understand what the code is doing instead of just giving them the code.